# GDI object HBRUSH translucent

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, gdi, brush

I am working with GDI and VS 6.0 for my application.
In my application the drawn polygons are overlapping , and I am filling each polygon with a specific color using `CreateSolidBrush`.The Regions are created using the [CRgn class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/077zk1zy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[image]
Now my problem is I want to make the underlying polygon to be some what visible ( by making the overlapping layer translucent). Same goes for underlying other shapes like ellipses,lines,text.[image]
Here I have used a `CreateHatchBrush`.

I know that the `HBRUSH` object can be assigned with a color or can be made transparent.
But what I want is something similar to [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.opacity%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984108%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)'s [Color(Alpha) property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms968443%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) 
GDI+ seemed to be an option but its not available with VS 6.0.

Any views on how can I achieve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- [`AlphaBlend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN
- [Using the AlphaBlend function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286/Using-the-AlphaBlend-function) on CodeProject

[image: AlphaBlend Example]

Comment: I am not handling bitmaps,I want to have this on individual regions created.

Comment: You will paint on a separate DC/bitmap and then alpha blend into the DC of interest.

Comment: @Shirish11 Can you created without bitmap? Please update answer.